# R metaprogramming: pass expression/quosure to function that partially accesses local frame

Tags: r, functional-programming, metaprogramming, rlang, tidyeval

I will use the following example to explain my question. But the question is not only about this specific example, but more general about meta-programming in R.

I have two specific functions to make plots

#### Specific function 1

```
draw_hists <- function(dts, indexs, title_prefix = 'sd = ') {
  mapply(
    function(dt, index) 
    {
      hist(dt, main = paste(title_prefix, as.character(index)))
    },
    dts, indexs
  )
}
```

plots histograms

```
sds <- c(0.1, 0.5, 5, 100)
raw_normals <- purrr::map(sds, ~rnorm(500, mean = 1, sd = .x))
draw_hists(raw_normals, sds)
```

[image]

#### Specific function 2

plots scatter plots of percentage ranks against raw data

```
draw_percentage <- function(dts, indexs, title_prefix = 'sd = ') {
  mapply(
    function(dt, index) 
    {
      plot(dt, dplyr::percent_rank(dt), main = paste(title_prefix, as.character(index)))
    },
    dts, indexs
  )
}

sds <- c(0.1, 0.5, 5, 100)
raw_normals <- purrr::map(sds, ~rnorm(500, mean = 1, sd = .x))
draw_percentage(raw_normals, sds)
```

[image]

Now assume I want to abstract out the general patterns of these functions and define a generic higher-order function that takes inputs of any arbitrary plotting function and its argument as an expression to be flexible enough drawing nearly whatever I want to draw. I thought something like this would work.

```
draw_generic <- function(dts, indexs, plfun, plfun_arguments_as_expr) { 
 ....
}
```

The formal parameter `plfun_arguments_as_expr` would bind to an expression such like `expr(dplyr::percent_rank(dt))` to make the plotting truly generic and flexible. I come up with the following solution.

```
draws_generic <- function(dts, indexs, plfun, title_prefix = 'sd =', ...) {
  dots <- enquos(...)
  mapply(
    function(dt, index) 
    {
      eval_tidy(
        expr(
          plfun(dt, main = paste(title_prefix, as.character(index)), !!!dots)
        )
      )
    }
    ,
    dts, indexs
  )
}

draws_generic(raw_normals, sds, hist)
draws_generic(raw_normals, sds, plot, dplyr::percent_rank(dt))
```

The histogram works. But the percent_rank one gives me error

```
Error in x[!nas] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'
Called from: rank(x, ties.method = "min", na.last = "keep")
```

I think this might be related to the fact that the environment scope captured by `enquos` is global, but the expression contains a name `dt` for which its binding existed in local scope created by the anonymous function `function(dt, index)`. Is this truly the reason of this error? If so, is there a neat and clean way to fix it that follows principles of "tidy evaluation"?

### Update

Inspired by the comments, I modify here my question. In stead of using a pure functional abstraction to generalize procedures, what I really want is to achieve generalization by treating code as object and manipulate it freely in a R function or kind of macro programming. More precisely what I want is a `draw_expression` function to plot data against a given expression instead of previous `draw_generic`. Below are some of my attempts so far:

The 1st version plots a plotting expression with `x` as data argument against given data without additional `indexs` parameter and title. The code has been tested working.

```
draw_expression_1 <- function(dts, plexpr) {
  plexpr <- enexpr(plexpr)
  lapply(dts, eval(expr(function(x) !!plexpr)))
}

draw_expression_1(raw_normals, hist(x))
draw_expression_1(raw_normals, plot(x, dplyr::percent_rank(x))
```

The 2nd version adds additional `indexs` parameter and titles by modifying the given expression. The code has been tested working.

```
draw_expression_2 <- function(dts, indexs, plexpr, title_prefix = 'sd =') {
  plexpr <- enexpr(plexpr)
  mapply(eval(expr(function(x, index) {
    UQ(rlang::call_modify(plexpr, main = quote(paste(title_prefix, as.character(index)))))
    })), dts, indexs)
}

draw_expression_2(raw_normals, sds, hist(x))
draw_expression_2(raw_normals, sds, plot(x, dplyr::percent_rank(x))
```

The 3rd version is aimed at allowing the call expression to have any arbitrary formal parameter name instead of `x`. Release the assumption to be that the 1st parameter corresponds to the data to be plotted, but it can be named whatever users wished.

```
draw_expression_3 <- function(dts, indexs, plexpr, title_prefix = 'sd =') {
  plexpr <- enexpr(plexpr)
  first_arg_name <- rlang::call_args(plexpr)
  mapply(eval(expr(function(first_arg_name, index) {
    UQ(rlang::call_modify(plexpr, main = quote(paste(title_prefix, as.character(index)))))
  })), dts, indexs)
}

draw_expression_3(raw_normals, sds, hist(x))
draw_expression_3(raw_normals, sds, plot(x, dplyr::percent_rank(x))
```

This prints me error:

```
Error in plot(x, dplyr::percent_rank(x), main = paste(title_prefix, as.character(index))) : 
  object 'x' not found
```

Apparently `first_arg_name` has to been unquoted in the expression. Thus I did this:

```
draw_expression_3 <- function(dts, indexs, plexpr, title_prefix = 'sd =') {
  plexpr <- enexpr(plexpr)
  first_arg_name <- rlang::call_args(plexpr)
  mapply(eval(expr(function(UQ(first_arg_name), index) {
    UQ(rlang::call_modify(plexpr, main = quote(paste(title_prefix, as.character(index)))))
  })), dts, indexs)
}

draw_expression_3(raw_normals, sds, hist(x))
draw_expression_3(raw_normals, sds, plot(x, dplyr::percent_rank(x))
```

But I got weird syntax error:

```
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
```

Now I don't understand why this happens. Any help?

Also I could not use `enquo` + `eval_tidy` here, since `enquo` will capture the environment of the call expression which is global, but the expression inside the function that I would like to modify and manipulate contains `x` which belongs to the inner scope. Thus this is not a tidy evaluation. But I am not perusing that anymore. I simply want do macro programming as freely as I can with base R plus some of convenient tools provided by `rlang`.

NOTE: I am not trying to do any production work. I am just trying to see the limit of this language and understand things better.

Comment: The scoping you're looking for seems a bit strange. I guess it would make sense by implementing `dt` as some sort of pronoun, i.e. an _anaphoric_ UI. But I agree with user255 that passing a function seems cleaner and easier.

Comment: The syntax error is actually the second syntax error in the `mapply(...)` expression.  The first one complains about `function(UQ(first_arg_name), index)`, because you can't use `UQ(first_arg_name)` as an argument name, though it could be a default value, e.g. `function(x = UQ(first_arg_name), index)` would be legal.

Comment: After the first error, the parser restarts, and that's why it complains about the `}`.

Comment: More generally, `eval(expr(foo))` is generally the same as `foo`, so several of your expressions could be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the "tidy evaluation" way to do this, but the simpler base R method is to pass a function rather than an expression.  For example,

```r
sds <- c(0.1, 0.5, 5, 100)
raw_normals <- purrr::map(sds, ~rnorm(500, mean = 1, sd = .x))

draws_generic2 <- function(dts, indexs, plfun, title_prefix = 'sd =') {
  mapply(
    function(dt, index) 
    {
      plfun(dt, main = paste(title_prefix, as.character(index)))
    },
    dts, indexs
  )
  invisible(NULL)
}

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
draws_generic2(raw_normals, sds, hist)
```

[image]

```r
draws_generic2(raw_normals, sds, function(dt, ...) plot(dt, dplyr::percent_rank(dt), ...))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I used `dt` in my function definition in the second example, but I could have used any variable name, e.g. this would give the same output except for the axis labels:

```
draws_generic2(raw_normals, sds, 
               function(x, ...) plot(x, dplyr::percent_rank(x), ...))
```

Comment: I don't think there is any tidyeval way to do this. I like your solution.

Comment: Indeed nice solution. Thanks. However, as I said at beginning, what I’m looking for is not just a solution for this specific question but more about a way to simulate macro with quoting and evaluation in R. Thanks for sharing the thoughts

Comment: @englealuze, you should modify your question to include an example that wouldn't work this way.  It doesn't really make sense to me for a user of `draws_generic` to need to know internal variable names in that function.  Maybe something like the use of `x` in `curve()`?

Comment: @user2554330 This comment inspired me. I think what I shouldn't do in the original post is to mix a classical functional approach with the meta programming which aimed at manipulating code. What I really want to do is the latter. As you suggested I have modified my question and added an update session. Please have a look